# Google Cloud update faile with "Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/..."

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

./appcfg.py --oauth2 --email= update

And I receive:

```
Authentication successful.
02:45 PM Scanning files on local disk.
02:45 PM Cloning 6 application files.
02:45 PM Starting deployment.
02:45 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
02:45 PM Deployment successful.
02:45 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
02:45 PM Will check again in 5 seconds.
02:45 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
02:45 PM Will check again in 5 seconds.
02:46 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
02:46 PM Will check again in 5 seconds.
02:46 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
02:46 PM Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 failed). Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/direct-plasma-755' Deployed Version: 42.379887589171696887
2014-11-05 14:46:07,986 ERROR appcfg.py:2582 Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 failed). Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/direct-plasma-755' Deployed Version: 42.379887589171696887 
02:46 PM Rolling back the update.  This can sometimes take a while since a VM version is being rolled back.
Could not start serving the given version.
```

The app.yaml is simplest, from Python tutorial. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you deploying a managed VM? Also, is it possible that your quotas are full in some regard and this is why the VM doesn't spin up? Also, sanity check, have you created the project for the given app-id (direct-plasma-755)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone else encounters this I got a problem with a similar error message and have just solved it.

I was using the Google "one click deploy" to deploy an elastic search cluster and got this error:  Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/....

All the quotas were fine.  It turns out that although the service a/c being used to provision this could happily create VMs & root disks it failed on creating the data disk.  I have to change the permissions of one of the service a/c's to "edit" and then it all started working.

I know its not exactly related to the above example,  but others who had my problem will get to this page,  so it might help them.

Comment: I myself worked it through by deleting the project and recreating. Dan's answer is more informative, I select it as an answer.